# Error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document in Spring Java (Marshaller)

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling

I am trying to POJO to XML using Marshaller.

[image: this is error]

and I want it to make XML like

```xml
<youthPolicyList>
  <respResult>resilt</respResult>
  <errMsg>200</errMsg>
  <totalCnt>123</totalCnt>
  <youthPolicyList>
    <bizId>...</bizId>
    <bizIdCode>...</bizIdCode>
    ...
  </youthPolicyList>
</youthPolicyList>
```

I made List for youthPolicyList values and result List. This is the VO for youthPolicyList values

```java
package egovframework.ksis.yipAPI;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class YipapiVO {
        
    // 정책사업 ID [ register_type (db) + register_date (db) + bizIdCode + bizIdNum ]
    @XmlElement
    private String bizId;
    @XmlElement
    private String bizIdCode;               // 정책사업구분코드 (코드표)
    @XmlElement
    private int bizIdNum;                   // 일련번호(5자리)
    
    // 수혜대상지역구분코드 small_category_sid (YIP.YOUTH_SMALL_CATEGORY)
    @XmlElement
    private String cntcTrgtDataSeq;
    
    // 지역 (정책사업구분코드를 위한 지역) 
    // [small_category_title - 매치해서 코드표 연결해야함]
    @XmlElement
    private String polyBizIscd; 
    
    @XmlElement
    private String polyBizSjnm;         // 정책사업제목 policy_title
    @XmlElement
    private String polyItcnCn;          // 정책소개내용 policy_summary
    @XmlElement
    private String sporCn;              // 지원 내용 policy_content
    @XmlElement
    private String sporScvl;            // 지원규모내용 policy_scale
    @XmlElement
    private String bizPrdCn;            // 사업운영기간 policy_start_date ~ policy_end_date
    @XmlElement
    private String prdRpttSecd;         // 기간 반복구분코드(코드표)
    @XmlElement
    private String rqutPrdCn;           // 사업신청기간 policy_apply_start_date ~ policy_apply_end_date
    
    @XmlElement
    private String bgnAge;              // 시작 연령
    @XmlElement
    private String endAge;              // 종료 연령
    
    @XmlElement
    private String majrRqisCn;          // 전공요건내용 policy_major  
    @XmlElement
    private String majorRqisSecdCn;     // 전공요건구분코드(코드표)
    
    @XmlElement
    private String empmSttsCn;          // 취업상태내용 policy_job_status
    @XmlElement
    private String empmSttsSecdCn;      // 취업상태구분코드(코드표)
    
    @XmlElement
    private String splzRlmRqisCn;       // 특화분야내용 policy_special
    @XmlElement
    private String splzRlmRqisSecdCn;   // 특화분야구분코드(코드표)
    
    @XmlElement
    private String accrRqisCn;          // 학력요건내용 policy_education
    @XmlElement
    private String accrRqisSecdCn;      // 학력요건구분코드(코드표)
    
    @XmlElement
    private String prcpCn;              // 거주지 및 소득조건 policy_location
    
    @XmlElement
    private String aditRscn;            // 추가단서사항 policy_added_item
    @XmlElement
    private String prcpLmttTrgtCn;      // 참여제한대상 policy_restrict
    @XmlElement
    private String rqutProcCn;          // 신청절차내용 policy_apply_step
    @XmlElement
    private String pstnPaprCn;          // 제출서류내용 policy_document
    @XmlElement
    private String jdgnPresCn;          // 심사및발표일정 policy_announce
    @XmlElement
    private String rqutUrla;            // 신청사이트주소 policy_apply_site 
    @XmlElement
    private String rfcSiteUrla1;        // 참고사이트URL 주소1 reference_site1
    @XmlElement
    private String rfcSiteUrla2;        // 참고사이트URL 주소2 reference_site2
    
    // 주관부처상세 및 운영자 상세 동일
    @XmlElement
    private String mngtMson;            // 주관부처명  policy_agency_name
    @XmlElement
    private String mngtMrofCherCn;      // 주관부터담장자이름(db에 없음)
    @XmlElement
    private String cherCtpcCn;          // 주관부처담당자연락처 policy_agency_tel
    @XmlElement
    private String operNmor;            // 운영자기관명 policy_agency_name
    @XmlElement
    private String tintCherCn;          // 운영기관담당자이름(db에 없음)
    @XmlElement
    private String tintCherCtpcCn;      // 운영기관담당자연락처policy_agency_tel
    
    @XmlElement
    private String etct;                // 기타사항내용 policy_notice
    @XmlElement
    private String tynm;                // 카테고리내용 policy_type_detail
    @XmlElement
    private String rmcn;                // 비고(db에 없음)
    @XmlElement
    private String lastCntcUpdtDt;      // 업데이트 데이트 없을경우 리지스트 데이터 사용 update_date
    
    // I / U / D
    @XmlElement
    private String cntcStcd;            // 연계상태코드
    
    @XmlElement
    private String frstRgstDt;          // 최초등록일시 register_date
    @XmlElement
    private String lastUpdtDt;          // 최초수정일시
    
    @XmlElement
    private String upprBizId;           // 상위사업Id

    public YipapiVO(String string) {
        
    }
}
```

And this for result VO

```java
package egovframework.ksis.yipAPI;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

// @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) // xml의 직렬화 범위를 결정
public class YipapiVOXML {
    
    public static class ResultValue{
        @XmlElement
        private String respResult;
        @XmlElement
        private String errMsg;
        @XmlElement
        private String totalCnt;
        
        public ResultValue(String string) {}
    }
    
    @XmlRootElement(name="youthPolicyList") // xml의 루트 태그를 의미 name을 명시하지 않으면 클래스명이 디폴트가 된다
    public static class APIList{
        // 결과 메세지 List
        @XmlElement
        List<ResultValue> resultValue = new ArrayList<>();
        
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "youthPolicy")
        @XmlElement     
        private List<YipapiVO> apiList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // ADD를 위한
        void addVoList(YipapiVO yipapiVO) {
            apiList.add(yipapiVO);
        }
        void addResult(ResultValue resultVal) {
            resultValue.add(resultVal);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is for parsing XML Controller.

```java
package egovframework.ksis.yipAPI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import egovframework.ksis.yipAPI.YipapiVOXML.APIList;
import egovframework.ksis.yipAPI.YipapiVOXML.ResultValue;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/yipapi")
public class YipapiContorller {
    
    @Value("${restApi.key}")
    private String restApiKey;

    @Value("${restApi.basisUrl}")
    private String basisUrl;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendxml", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        
        // Determine content type
        String format = request.getParameter("format");
        if (format == null || format.equalsIgnoreCase("XML")) {
            response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("JSON")) {
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        }

        try {
            Writer responseWriter = response.getWriter();
            
            APIList apiList = new APIList();
            
            ResultValue respResult = new ResultValue("응답결과");
            apiList.addResult(respResult);
            ResultValue errMsg = new ResultValue("에러메세지");
            apiList.addResult(errMsg);
            ResultValue totalCnt = new ResultValue("토탈");
            apiList.addResult(totalCnt);
            
            YipapiVO bizId = new YipapiVO("bizId");
            apiList.addVoList(bizId);
                
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(YipapiVOXML.class);
            Marshaller  marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            
            StringWriter xml = new StringWriter(); 
            
            // 보기 좋게 출력
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            
            // 표준 출력으로 결과 보여줌
            marshaller.marshal(apiList, responseWriter);
            System.out.println(xml);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also error appear on console.

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Class *** nor any of its super class is
> known to this context

Am I missing something?

Comment: Now if only Spring would support this itself instaed of you messing around with xml marshalling. Just reutn the `APIList` from the method instead of void and remove all the stuff doing nasty things with XML marshalling.

Comment: For future reference, snippets are **only** intended for use with HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions. For any other language, use normal code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the formatting, ditch the XML code just return `APIList` from the method.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/yipapi")
public class YipapiContorller {
    
  @Value("${restApi.key}")
  private String restApiKey;

  @Value("${restApi.basisUrl}")
  private String basisUrl;
    
    
  @GetMapping("/sendxml")
  @ResponseBody
  public APIList doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
        
    APIList apiList = new APIList();
          
    ResultValue respResult = new ResultValue("응답결과");
    apiList.addResult(respResult);
    ResultValue errMsg = new ResultValue("에러메세지");
    apiList.addResult(errMsg);
    ResultValue totalCnt = new ResultValue("토탈");
    apiList.addResult(totalCnt);
            
    YipapiVO bizId = new YipapiVO("bizId");
    apiList.addVoList(bizId);
    return apiList;
  }
}
```

Spring will do the marshalling for you (assuming you have the proper annotations).

In your current code you are working against/around the capabilities of the framework instead of embracing them.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum
thank you for comment. if i just return APIList, the xml appear json. because i am using json library for other code.. that is why i am using marshaller for parsing xml.
i think i need to search more on google then fix all my code haha
thank you!

Comment: If you get JSON that is because your client is requesting JSON, if he requests XML Spring will send XML. So you need to make sure you send a request with an `Accept: application/xml` as a header.